# Dividing two number without losing precision

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I am dividing two numbers `466489/249001` which results in **Non-terminating decimal expansion**.

> As the `BigDecimal` class stores floating-point numbers with practically unlimited precision, I have gone for it.

```
    BigDecimal dividend = BigDecimal.valueOf(466489L);
    BigDecimal divisor  = BigDecimal.valueOf(249001L);
    System.out.println((double)466489/249001);
    //1.8734422753322275
    System.out.println(dividend.divide(divisor, MathContext.DECIMAL128));
    //1.873442275332227581415335681382806
```

From [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=466489/249001) I am getting the result as

> 1.87344227533222758141533568138280569154340745619495504034120344898213260187710089517712780269958755185722145694193999220...

So I suppose my result is precise.

Now I want to know how can I get more precision in my result using `BigDecimal` as calculated by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=466489/249001)?

Comment: Well you see where you're specifying `MathContext.DECIMAL128`? Have you tried specifying a `MathContext` with more decimal places?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have tried `MathContext.UNLIMITED` but I am getting Exception _java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum precision in BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990701/maximum-number-of-digits-after-the-decimal-point-using-bigdecimal).

Comment: Well yes, you would - as you said, it's a non-terminating decimal expansion. So you need to know what precision you need, and represent it that way. Either that, or just keep it as a fraction...

Comment: @Shaan since the expression is non-terminating you can't use `MathContext.UNLIMITED` otherwise you'd kill your VM. Provide a big enough limit and all should be fine.

Comment: So if I use `new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode)`, which Rounding mode is more precise `HALF_UP` or `HALF_EVEN`?

Comment: @Shaan that depends on your needs, the prefined contexts all use `HALF_EVEN` but I'd probably go with `HALF_UP` since according to the doc `HALF_EVEN` would round 2.5 to 2 which would not be what I'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to provide a `MathContext` instance with custom precision, e.g.

```
dividend.divide(divisor, new MathContext( 100 ) ); //whatever precision you need
```

Comment: So if I use new MathContext(1000, RoundingMode), which Rounding mode is more precise HALF_UP or HALF_EVEN?

Comment: "More precise" is an ill-defined term.  Look at the actual docs to see how rounding is done.

Answer (score 0):

You could set scale with appropriate rounding to achieve this

```
System.out.println(dividend.divide(divisor,49,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
```

I get the following output : 1.8734422753322275814153356813828056915434074561950

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions posted by others involving using a `MathContext` there is always the possibility that a good `Rational` class may be useful.

See [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/Rational.java.html) for a good one.

You should maintain your number as a `Rational` to keep full accuracy and only render it into a decimal when saving it - at that point, of course, you will need to truncate again.

It is potentially possible to recover the inaccuracies - but not in a reliable way and it requires some maths. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230266/823393) for my technique.